# onFocus .css and onblur .css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, onblur, onfocus

My HTML has a placeholder like such:

```
<input id="additionalsearch" type="text" value="Search Within" onfocus="if (this.value=='Search Within')this.value='';" onblur="if (this.value=='')this.value='Search Within';">
```

It wasn't my choice and I can't really remove it... but I was wondering how I can set the CSS too... I want to do something like `onfocus="if (this.value=='Search Within')this.value=''; $(this).css('color','000000');"` and `onblur="if (this.value=='')this.value='Search Within';$(this).css('color', 'A9A9A9');"`. How can I accomplish that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you pretty much provided the code with the exception of two mistakes:

1. You need a # before your colors.
2. You need to wrap your conditionals in braces

Everything else was fine (I changed the colors to make it more obvious what was happening):

```
<input id="additionalsearch" type="text" value="Search Within" onfocus="if (this.value=='Search Within'){this.value='';$(this).css('color','#00ff00');}" onblur="if (this.value==''){this.value='Search Within';$(this).css('color', '#ff0000');}">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/A4cuy/6/

Of course, this ends up being really ugly code and you are advised to put the javascript in separate handlers.

Comment: I guess his goal is to use a more elegant solution than ugly inlining of JavaScript into HTML. CSS would solve the case with the colors, the default value still needs JavaScript.

"... but I was wondering how I can set the CSS too."

Comment: That wasn't stated as far I can see, but as I have said it is preferable. Maybe I misread it.

Comment: @Ivo this is actually what I was looking for since your solution would change the text color when there text in the box.

Answer (score 3):

You can use pseudo-selectors:

```
input[type=text]:focus {
  color: black;
}

input[type=text] {
  color: gray;
}
```

Comment: But the problem is, if theres text in there, the color will also be changed. I want the colors to behave like an HTML5 placeholder in WebKit

Comment: You can set the text's color explicitly. If it still inherits the color of the text box, put an !important at the end of the rule.

Also, there is no :blur pseudo-class (at least I did not manage to find a documentation). For the blurred case, just use "#additionalsearch" only and let the :focus case override it.

Comment: But now if a user enter a keywords. Then blurs out the text box the color is changed to gray. I only want it to be Gray when the value is Search Within

Comment: I see. Just use this: http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/defaultInputText
Or this: http://www.dailycoding.com/Posts/default_text_fields_using_simple_jquery_trick.aspx

Comment: True Ivo, I changed the answer for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pseudo-class :focus for the color
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_focus.asp

As for the "Search Within" thing, I recommend using the defaultText jQuery plug-in

http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/defaultInputText

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following

```
$('#additionalsearch')
.bind('focus',function(){
       if (this.value=='Search Within'){
             this.value='';
        };
        $(this).css('color','black')})
.bind('blur',function(){
       if (this.value==''){
          this.value='Search Within';
       }           
       $(this).css('color','gray')});
```

Answer (score 0):

Tast this:

```
<input id="fldnm" style="background:#B6FF00" type="text" value="Search"
  onfocus="if(this.value=='Search'){this.value=''}this.style='background:#FF7F7F';"
  onblur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Search'this.style='background:#B6FF00';}else{};"
   />
```